# C++/Win32 API Performance profiling / timing

Tags: optimization, winapi

I am using Visual Studio 2008 at the moment. I would like to know if there is a way I could test the performance of my memory management library against the Win32 memory management API using free tools, or using code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Win32 memory management API"? It's essentially impossible to to allocate memory in any Windows process without using the underlying Windows memory management functions. Some details will help.

Comment: I have made a memory management library that exposes allocation and freeing functions. I would like to know if they are faster or slower than the Windows GlobalAlloc() and GlobalFree() functions. It is likely they are faster because my heap keeps a list of free nodes and there is less code for checking handles. However, I don't see any way you could measure this because the performance would depend on the heap fragmentation.

Comment: school Rules it's certainly easy to beat the performance of GlobalAlloc and GlobalFree but then most people just use the built in memory allocator (e.g. malloc) in their run time libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many malloc benchmarks out there, for example [this one](http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/linux-scalability/reports/malloc.html).